# Powershell: choose folder by version number

Tags: powershell

I'm writing a PowerShell script that goes into a couple of folders and runs a `.bat` file inside said folders. These folders are frequently updated and I only need to run the script from the newest folder of a certain type.

The folders look something like this:

```
Core_1.1.2
Core_1.3.4
Core_1.4.1
Extras_1.0.4
Extras_1.2.5
Extras_1.3.8
etc_1.1.2
etc_1.1.9
etc_1.2.6
```

Using the above folders as an example, I would need to go into `Core_1.4.1`, `Extras_1.3.8`, and `etc_1.2.6` and run a file called `run.bat` which exists in each one of those directories.

So what I would need is to find the highest version in `Core_*`, the highest version in `Extras_*`, etc.

If there was some way to get an array of folder names with a specific prefix, then sort the elements of that array alphanumerically and return the last item in the array that would work perfectly. I'd like to stay away from choosing folder based on modification dates as that might be problematic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a System.Version class which can help do the parsing and sorting for you. This solves problems caused by comparing strings. Comparing strings will result in lexicographic sorts where 1.10.0 is "lower" than 1.2.0. This not the typical order used when comparing version numbers. Something like this could work to find the newest "Core" folders:

```
$core = ls -Filter Core_* | sort { [version]($_.Name -replace '^.*_(\d+(\.\d+){1,3})$', '$1') } -Descending | select -Index 0
```

Then it just a matter of calling the bat file:

```
 & "$($core.FullName)\activate.bat"
```

Comment: Good catch. I had a feeling that a class existed, but I didn't bother to look :)

Comment: @FrodeF. I figured I'd post this bc its a little cleaner even though yours does the job fine. I actually didn't know you could get sort to work like that.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you. tested and working perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

My first idea would be something like this:

```
$versions = { [int]($_.Name -replace '.*?_(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)', '$1') }, { [int]($_.Name -replace '.*?_(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)', '$2') }, { [int]($_.Name -replace '.*?_(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)', '$3') }

#Get folders
Get-ChildItem |
#Extract versions and sort highest first
Sort-Object $versions -Descending |
#Get first item/folder (highest version)
Select-Object -First 1


    Directory: C:\Users\Frode\Desktop\test


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d----        29.08.2014     18:43            Core_1.4.1
```

Comment: Actually, I believe this is incorrect after testing it. It compares the version parts as strings and therefore versions like 1.10.0 will be lower than 1.2.0.

Comment: Yes it it, sorry. It's a typo after I edited the answer :) My first attempt was `[int]($_.Name -replace '\D')` until I realised that there was something called 10.0.0, 1.10.0 etc. verisons. Forgot to add the cast in the new solution :)

Answer (score 1):

I'll offer an alternative using a RegEx, Group, and some string combining.

```
PS C:\Users> $Folders = Get-ChildItem $path -directory | Where{$_.name -match "(.+?_)(.*)$"} | ForEach{[pscustomobject]@{'base'=$matches[1];'version'=$matches[2]}} | group base | ForEach{($_.Name)+($_.group|select -last 1 -ExpandProperty version)}

PS C:\Users> $Folders 
Core_1.4.1
Extras_1.3.8
BP_1.2.6

PS C:\Users> $Folders | ForEach{& "$path\$_\BatchFile.bat"}
```

**Edit:** I love how people mark down things but don't bother to comment as to why they marked them down. My answer is functional for the OP's purposes.

Comment: I believe ls -Filter is faster than iterating over each directory. Also I like the -directory option ... but it's a property of Get-ChildItem . I doubt your solution work, did u try it?

Comment: You're right, it was intended to be `Get-ChildItem` and not `Get-Content`. I have corrected my answer, and the updated answer does work (tested with the OP's example listing).